# Blinking cursor after ubuntu 20.04 installation

Tags: boot, 20.04

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a laptop using the advanced option and removing the Windows drive. The installation succeeded successfully but after the restart and removing the USB, it only shows the Acer logo and then a blinking cursor. On pressing F2 and F12, the boot option (F2) and boot order (F12) also do not appear.

I tried to reboot using the USB and it also does not work (which I thought should work because the USB is on the top of the list of boot order already).

I tried a few things after googling but most solutions have at least some option to run the commands, or boot from USB, neither of which I have. Any possible solution will be appreciated.

Hardware specs: acer aspire 5250 E304g32mikk, model number P5we6

Comment: Try if you're are able to login in tty, with ctrl + alt + F1-12, you should see a login screen

Comment: *it only shows the Acer logo and then a blinking cursor. The boot option (F2) and boot order (F12) also do not work* Of course they don't work, they would have to be pressed before that. Please edit your question and post hardware specifications, namely the graphics, because that's a problem with the desktop not running likely due to lack of graphics drivers or Secure Boot enabled in UEFI.

Comment: @lucki1000 I tried that already. No login screen by any of these combinations. I mean still the same blinking cursor.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Of course, I meant that I pressed these keys and by not working, I meant the expected boot options or boot order do not appear. I have edited it to clarify it further. Also I have added hardware specs.

Comment: I'm sure you're capable of understanding that any firmware option needs to be triggered before the OS starts loading (or trying to). It's too late if the blinking cursor shows up. They need to be pressed (and probably spammed) *immediately* after powering on. Once you access UEFI settings first thing to try is to disable Fast Boot and Secure Boot.